# Simply trying to scroll down, every 1 second, in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the `setTimeout` function 3 times, but for some reason it does not work. I was under the impression that I had to use the `clearTimeout`:

```
handle = setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 1000);
window.clearTimeout(handle)

handle = setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 1000);
window.clearTimeout(handle)

handle = setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 1000);
window.clearTimeout(handle)
```

But this doesn't work. I'm not sure why. I'm learning out the timeout handle every time before running the next one. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Using the `setInterval()` function results in me getting another error. Here's the example:

```
var myVar = setInterval(scrollDown(), 5000);

function scrollDown() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1500);
}
```

and the error from the console:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
>   not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample'
>   'sha256-6gLjSWp3GRKZCUFvRX5aGHtECD1wVRgJOJp7r0ZQjV0='

So I get that there's a Content Security Policy enabled, but what does scrolling down have to do with this? Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: All of your timeouts start at the same time and are cleared immmediately after they are started. The rest of the code doesn't wait for the timeout to complete before executing. You have to not clear them, then declare the next one inside the current, or use an interval

Comment: Thanks @TinyGiant. Much appreciated. Going to try with the setInterval route.

Comment: You're assigning the result of `scrollDown()` as the callback for `setTimeout`. It should be `setInterval(scrollDown, 5000)`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks man! Did not know about this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to clear the timeout, as that will cancel your pending function call. Instead try calling setTimeout with 3 different intervals (1000, 2000, 3000) or use setInterval and cancel after the 3rd call

```
// setTimeout
setTimeout(function(){
  window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
  window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
  window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
}, 3000);

// setInterval
var i = 0;
var handle = setInterval(function(){
  window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
  i++;
  if (i === 3) {
    clearInterval(handle);
  }
}, 1000);
```